# CCS Error With MakeFile "makefile_ccs_bootimage_gen:69: recipe for target 'all' failed"

Tags: makefile

When building a project you get the error of building a make file. See below for a solution I found

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error, you need to give CCS / TI an exclusion in your antivirus / windows defender! (I posted this question as it was tricky to find an answer on the web and hope others find this helpful!)

Image of what it looks like if you did it right:

[image]